# Having issues with this error, "key word not supported, initial catalog

Tags: c#, entity-framework

am having a simple e-commerce project. the problem is that whenever I run the project, I get this error "Key word not supported, initial catalog".
Below is my connection string...

```
<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial
Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>.
```

I also have the following Ninject controller factory...

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Ninject;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;   
using Moq;
using SportsStore.Domain.Concrete;
namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;
    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
    requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
        ? null
        : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }
    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does it help if you escape '\' as '\\'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyword not supported: 'data source'.: EF code-first using ObjectContext and LocalDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087430/keyword-not-supported-data-source-ef-code-first-using-objectcontext-and-loc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection String problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228020/connection-string-problem) most likely it's `Database=SportsStore` instead of `Initial
Catalog=SportsStore`.

Comment: Andreas, I am really grateful for your answer. I made the change in the connection string and its now working...